# Windows shows all Wi-Fi networks except mine

Tags: windows, wireless-networking

Sometimes, usually after waking laptop from sleep, Windows doesn't connect to internet. When I open networks list, it shows all nearby Wi-Fi networks except my Wi-Fi. At the same time, my smart phone is connected to my Wi-Fi network.
Once I shut down the Windows when this situation happened and booted to LinuxMint. It immediately connected to my Wi-Fi. Then I started Windows again and it failed to find my Wi-Fi. So there is no hardware problem. Such thing never happened on any other OS.
I tried driver update, Windows reset, Windows update, sfc and dism. No success.
Sometimes when I disable and re-enable wireless network adapter in device manager, it finds my network.
What could be the problem?

System Info:
Acer Aspire E1-572G
Windows 10 Pro 20270.0 (Insider Preview)
Qualcomm Atheros AR956x Wireless Network Adapter / Driver Version: 10.0.3.462
ZyXEL DEL1201-T10A Wireless Modem

Comment: Open an admin command prompt in Windows and delete the wireless profile.  netsh wlan delete profile name=profilename . Then in Device Manager, delete the wireless adapter (You should download the newest driver first of course). Restart, install the newest wireless driver and make a new Wireless connection profile. Try that - I do that on my own and customer machines.

Comment: Please try the following method: Locate to Wi-Fi connection in Network connections->Right click it and select properties->In Wi-Fi Properties, click Configuration->Select Advanced tab->Select Country Region (2.4GHz) and set its' value to **#0(1-11)** and click OK

Comment: @John I tried your solution. No difference. I also tried different driver versions again.

Comment: @Sunny I can't find "Configuration" in "Wi-Fi Properties".